# @media (max-width) and mobile browsers

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

I am really helpless with this problem, please advice.

I have web page that I want to optimize (with CSS media queries) for mobile devices. In `<head>`, I have this:

```
<meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="True">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes" />
```

But some problems appear when testing media queries:

1) Testing on my Huawei Ideos X1, which has display width 240px. So, CSS should look like this:

```
@media (max-width: 240px) {
    body: { background-color: red; }
}
```

but it do nothing.

2) "Where could be problem?" I said. So, I am giving javascript for displaying screen resolution to the `<body>`:

```
<div>
    <script>
    document.write(screen.width + 'x' + screen.height);
    </script>
</div>
```

But it shows "320x425". This is weird, my mobile has screen width 240px, not 320.

3) Doesn't matter. I read about mobile browsers which auto-zoom thats content for displaying more content into one screen. Maybe my mobile browser zoomed out and now display area 320 px width. So, I am adding two lines to the `<body>`. One with width 240px, second with width 320px. Expect both to render in mobile browser without scrollbars, climbed to the screen:

```
<hr style="width: 240px;">
<hr style="width: 320px;">
```

To my surprise, screen was climbed with first line (240px), the second line (320px) went out of the screen (for 80px) and horizontal scroolbar appears.

**So, to cut a long story short:** Javascript thinks to have 320px wide screen available. CSS thinks to have 320px wide screen available. But only 240px can fit into the screen. Similar behavior shows on my friends iPhone.

Please advice me, where is my mystake? Thank you.

P.S. Test source code can be found there: http://pastebin.com/ULNm4RfW

Answer (score 0):

I think one of your issues could be resolved if you designed with a mobile-first method. That means design for the smallest screen size (mobile) and then move your way up to larger.

Your css would turn from max-width to min-width values, like so...

```
@media screen and (min-width: 240px) {
    CSS: here;
}
```

So all of your basic styles that you set in the beginning would be for the smaller screen sizes, and the rule above would set styles starting with any screen size 240px or above.

This also will remove the need to use any JavaScript, which you should try to avoid using when browser sniffing screen sizes.

Comment: Both, min-width or max-width, CSS thinks that my phone has display with 320px width, not 240px.